# Steps or steps missing when manually starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

My Rails application is running fine in my local development enviroment (Mac). I pushed the code to a test server, and trying to start it manually, but getting an error. The details are:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Rails 5.2.3
Ruby 2.6.3
Puma
Webpacker
Nginx
```

my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myfqdn.com.conf file:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/test/shared/tmp/sockets/test-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name test.xxxxxx.com;

  root /home/amptest/public;
  access_log /home/test/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/test/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I created the directories:

```
/home/myapp/shared
/home/myapp/shared/tmp
/home/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets
/home/myapp/shared/tmp/pids
```

my config/puma.rb, has the following:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
plugin :tmp_restart
```

In my .bashrc, I have:

```
export RAILS_ENV='test'
```

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
gem 'puma'
gem 'webpacker'
```

I ran:

```
bundle install
```

With no errors

And successfully did db migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

and seeded the DB:

```
rake db:seed
```

Then I did:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Which completed properly:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
2019-09-10 01:36:10 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
yarn install v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.76s.
I, [2019-09-10T01:36:13.413669 #3461]  INFO -- : Writing /home/myapp/public/assets/express/lib/application-9232ebdb20ad39572e70fb9e29810e63dbb63b58f5f18617c7c2bc8bd28321b5.js
I, [2019-09-10T01:36:13.413941 #3461]  INFO -- : Writing /home/myapp/public/assets/express/lib/application-9232ebdb20ad39572e70fb9e29810e63dbb63b58f5f18617c7c2bc8bd28321b5.js.gz
Compiling…
Compiled all packs in /home/test/public/packs-test
```

But I try to go to test.xxxxxx.com, I get the error "Something Went Wrong".

The nginx error log says:

```
2019/09/10 05:38:21 [crit] 1192#1192: *1 connect() to unix:///home/test/shared/tmp/sockets/test-puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx, server: test.xxxxxx.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/test/shared/tmp/sockets/test-puma.sock:/", host: "test.xxxxxx.com"
2019/09/10 05:38:47 [info] 1192#1192: *3 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

So, I am missing a step or more, including what I need to do to make sure Puma is properly started. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the app's rails server is not running. You never ran `rails server` command.

If you're using this for test/development purposes, consider this:

- Start the rails server at port 3001, `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001`
- Then in nginx config use rails server URL to Reverse proxy requests:

  ```
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001
  ```

If you're using this for production, then consider using [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/basics/ruby/fundamental_concepts.html) and you can see passenger installation [docs here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/install_passenger_main.html)

Comment: This is not on my local system. It's on a remote server on AWS. The application specifies puma not passenger

Comment: Are you sure your `rails server` cmd didn't throw any error?

Comment: I switched to passenger, and when I start the server, I don't get any errors. I am still getting getting a 404 not found error

Comment: This is the test sever, so RAILS_ENV=test